# How i can solve this error: Console can't read data

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I'm coding a Minecraft plugin (my first **"**real**"** plugin the others were tests) but I don't know why this error is happening.

*«I don't know how this error is called & most of this thread is in Spanish because I'm from Ecuador »*

I guess this code produces this error:

```java
 @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN+"Anti-lag enabled);
    }
```

or is in the `plugin.yml`: **⬇️**

```
# This plugin is private...  
name: Anti-lag
version: 1.16.1.0.1
api-version: 1.16.1 
# Added in Stack Overflow: Idk if the API version is correct.
author: me

main: private.private.antilag.anti_lag
# -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

If you want to read the all server (console) logs click in the link below.

[Click Here for the full server thread.](https://hastebin.com/uxoxijudel.java).

```java
[17:26:29 ERROR]: Failed to read console input
java.io.IOException: Invalid controller
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.SimpleTerminalConsole.readCommands(SimpleTerminalConsole.java:180) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.SimpleTerminalConsole.start(SimpleTerminalConsole.java:143) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer$1.run(DedicatedServer.java:66) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Controlador no válido
        at java.io.FileInputStream.close0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.access$000(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.FileInputStream$1.close(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.close(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implClose(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.close(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.close(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at java.io.BufferedReader.close(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
        at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.SimpleTerminalConsole.readCommands(SimpleTerminalConsole.java:183) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
        at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.SimpleTerminalConsole.start(SimpleTerminalConsole.java:143) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer$1.run(DedicatedServer.java:66) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
```

Thanks if you help me i'll be observant of your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats on your first plugin! Looks like the error is indeed being caused by the API version in your plugin.yml:

```
[17:26:33 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\Anti-lag.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Unsupported API version 1.16.1
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.util.CraftMagicNumbers.checkSupported(CraftMagicNumbers.java:290) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:133) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:397) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:305) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:388) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:208) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:941) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:177) ~[patched_1.16.1.jar:git-Paper-131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

Switching "api-version: 1.16.1" to "api-version: 1.16" should [resolve the problem](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/#optional-attributes). When using api-version, you only need to use the major release numbers (such as 1.13, 1.14, etc.) and not the minor release numbers (1.13.1, 1.14.2, etc.).

Strangely enough, the "Invalid Controller" error seems to be a bug [within Minecraft itself](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-33041), but luckily "should not have any side effects and can be ignored" according to Mojang's explanation. Nothing you did :)